# Function running after a component is no longer being rendered (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I will preface this by saying I am very new to react

I am trying to switch between a main menu component and a Lobby component when a button is clicked within the menu component by lifting state up from the menu component (as shown below):

```
import React from "react";
import MenuPage from './Menu.js'

class GamePage extends React.Component {

constructor(){
    super()
    this.state = {
        inLobby: false
    }
    this.setInLobby = this.setInLobby.bind(this)
    this.onBackClick = this.onBackClick.bind(this)
}

onBackClick(){
    this.setState({inLobby : false})
}

setInLobby(status) {
    this.setState({
       inLobby: status 
    });
}

render(){
    return (
        <div>
         {this.state.inLobby === true && 
         (
         <button onClick = {this.onBackClick}>Hello World</button>)}
         {this.state.inLobby === false && (<MenuPage setInLobby = {this.setInLobby}/>)}
         </div>
    )
   }
}
export default GamePage;
```

My menu screen
[image]

The code for my MenuPage:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import LobbyBanner from './Banner.js';
import MenuButton from "./Buttons.js";
import firebase from "./firebase.js";

class MenuPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    console.log(props);
    super();
    this.state = {
        Name: "Sebastian",
        Game_Key: "",
    }
    this.setName = this.setName.bind(this)
    this.setLobby = this.setLobby.bind(this)
    this.createLobby = this.createLobby.bind(this)
}

setName(){
    this.setState({
        Name: document.querySelector("#name").value,
        Game_Key: this.state.Game_Key,
    })
}

setLobby() {
    var lobby = document.querySelector("#game_input").value
    this.setState({
        Name: this.state.Name,
        Game_Key: document.querySelector("#game_input").value,
    })
    var firestore = firebase.firestore();  
    var docRef = firestore.doc("Games/Game " + document.querySelector("#game_input").value);
    docRef.get()
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
      if ((docSnapshot.exists)){
            docRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
                docRef.update({
                    players : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(document.querySelector("#name").value)
                }) 
            });
            this.props.setInLobby(true);
        } 
      else {
        this.setState({
            Name: this.state.Name,
            Game_Key: "Not found",
        })
        return;
      }
  });
}

createLobby() {
    var random_num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
    this.setState({
        Name: this.state.Name,
        Game_Key: random_num,
    })
    var firestore = firebase.firestore();  
    var docRef = firestore.doc("Games/Game " + random_num);
    docRef.set({
        PlayerAmnt: 1
    })
    docRef.update({
        players : firebase.firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(this.state.Name)
    })
}


render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
            <h1>{this.state.Name}</h1>
            </div>
            <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
            <h1>Lobby: {this.state.Game_Key}</h1>
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <input type="textfield" id="name"></input>
                <MenuButton 
                    style={{fontSize: "30px"}} 
                    text="Name" 
                    onClick={this.setName}
                />
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div style={{display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <input type="textfield" id="game_input"></input>
                <MenuButton 
                    style={{fontSize: "30px"}} 
                    text="Join game"
                    onClick={this.setLobby}
                />
                <MenuButton 
                    style={{fontSize: "30px"}} 
                    text="Host Game"
                    onClick={this.createLobby}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    )

    }
}

export default MenuPage;
```

My issue: I am using firebase to create lobbies for a simple game. Essentially the join code input is used to find the lobby, and if a lobby is found, the main menu screen is no longer rendered and the gamepage state is updated to change to the "Hello word" button, my code is (included above):
[image]

In theory my code should set the state of the menu screen to the new game key, check if the key is valid, perform the necessary operations, then change the state of GamePage to render the button, meaning the MenuPage methods are no longer being run, right? Or am i missing something? Because I get the following error:
[image]
I guess it is trying to read the text input that is no longer being rendered, but why is that function still being called even when the component is no longer rendering? I tried to do a simple if(document.querySelector("#name")) to avoid the statement if it doesn't exist, but it just leads to more errors down the road so I figure I should solve it properly. I'm not sure what I should even try to do since this seems like a fundemental misunderstanding of how react works. Can someone offer any insight?

edit: this is my index.js that actually renders the component

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import MenuPage from './Menu.js'
import firebase from "./firebase.js";
import Lobbylist from "./lobbylist.js";
import GamePage from "./Gamepage.js";

ReactDOM.render(<GamePage/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

you could use `?` to check if it is not null

`document.querySelector("#name").?value`

and you might want to do all thing that query elements, after the component has been rendered to make sure the elements you query are already there.

you can use `componentDidMount` to add code to run after render.

```
componentDidMount() {
     document.querySelector("#name").?value
}
```

[componentDidMount() doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount)